# DataGrip setting SQL_SAFE_UPDATES to ON by default

Tags: mysql, datagrip

MySQL Workbench seemed to always have `SQL SAFE UPDATES` on by default which is really nice when working with our production database.

Is there a way to accomplish this with DataGrip?  By default, it looks like `SQL_SAFE_UPDATES` is OFF by default.

An initialization script or JDBC driver option would work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can set this via the *sessionVariable* option within DataGrip.

1. Go to **File > Data Sources** and select your connection from the list of Project Data Source.
2. Go to the **Advanced** tab which lists *a lot* of variables.
3. Locate the the variable named **sessionVariables**. (*Tip: You can search for a particular variable by selecting any variable name, then start typing to seek.*)
4. Set the value for the variable to, `SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1`

Answer (score 2):

There is no possibility of that kind in DataGrip for now.

I created a ticket in the tracker, please watch and vote.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2606

Comment: The ticket has been updated with the answer from @user2045006.